# Algebraic objects and lifts of their represented functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, representable-functors

I've seen the following theorem around in various forms:

To give an object $A \in \mathcal{C}$ the structure of a $\Omega$-algebra object in $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to giving a lift of the contravariant hom-functor $\mathcal{C}(-,A) \colon \mathcal{C} \to Set$ to a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \Omega$.

Here $\Omega$ denotes the category of $\Omega$-algebra objects in $Set$.

However, despite much searching I've been unable to find a proof in the reverse direction. My particular question is given a lift of the hom-functor, how can we define the maps giving $A$ the structure of a $\Omega$-algebra object.

EDIT: After the answer by Dimitri, here's my attempt at a proof:

Let $h_A = \mathcal{C}(-,A) \colon \mathcal{C}\to Set$ and suppose that this lifts.

$h_A$ is an $\Omega$-algebra object in the functor category $[\mathcal{C}, Set]$. Let's suppose for an example that our $\Omega$-algebra, has a multiplication $\mu$. Then we have a natural transformation $\mu \colon h_A \times h_A \to h_A$.

The Yoneda embedding now tells us we have an isomorphism $Nat(h_{A \times A}, h_A) = \mathcal{C}(A \times A, A)$. Since $h_{A \times A}$ is isomorphic to $h_A \times h_A$ we see our natural transformation specifies a map $A \times A \to A$.

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving a functor $C \rightarrow \Omega$ is the same as giving an object with an $\Omega$-algebra structure in the category of functors $[C, Set]$. Having observed this the theorem follows form Yoneda and the fact that it preserves products.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, I've been trying to prove this myself, as you can see in the edit, but have been running into a little trouble, could you point me in the right direction?

Ideally, I'd like a constructive proof for a concrete setting, e.g. for $\Omega$ being algebras over a commutative ring. Is there a more straightforward way to do this then trying to unwind everything the Yoneda lemma tells us?

Comment: $h_A\times h_A$ is isomorphic to $h_{A\times A}$. This is because Yoneda preserves products, and pretty much the definition of a product. Then you use Yoneda $Nat(h_{A\times A}, h_A) \cong C(A\times A, A)$. That is the fact that Yoneda is fully faithful

Comment: Btw, perhaps this question was more appropriate for math.stackexchange

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your help. Do you have any insight over how easy it would be to do this in a constructive manner? The other direction in the equivalence is very easy to do constructively.

I didn't realise math.stackexchange and mathoverflow were different things, and agree with you. Is it possible to move this question?

Comment: You're wellcomed :) Not sure what do you mean by constructive, but e.g. to get the operation $A\times A \rightarrow A$ you evaluate $h_A\times h_A(A\times A) \rightarrow h_A (A\times A)$ at $(p_1, p_2)$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the two projections $A\times A \rightarrow A$.

Comment: Mathoverflow is a site for researchers. So indeed, questions which do not relate to original research better be asked at math.stackoverflow. Moving or deleting is done by administrators once they deem it necessary.

Comment: Perhaps maximally explicitly: given any $n$-ary operation $\omega$ on $\Omega$-algebras, here is how to equip $A$ with it. Since $\mathcal C(X,A)$ is an $\Omega$-algebra naturally for any $X$, in particular $\mathcal C(A^n,A)$ is. Then further in particular the result of applying $\omega$ to any $n$ elements of the $\Omega$-algebra $\mathcal C(A^n,A)$ is defined. So further in particular $\omega(\pi_1,...,\pi_n)\in\mathcal C(A^n,A)$ is defined, where $\pi_1,...,\pi_n\in\mathcal C(A^n,A)$ are the product projections. This is your $\omega_A:A^n\to A$.

Comment: And then one checks that the identities that $\Omega$-algebras must satisfy translate into commutative diagrams that these operations $\omega_A$ will fit in. For that one uses the fact that not only every $\mathcal C(X,A)$ is an $\Omega$-algebra but also every $\mathcal C(f,A):\mathcal C(X,A)\to\mathcal C(Y,A)$ is an $\Omega$-algebra homomorphism for any $f:Y\to X$ in $\mathcal C$.

Comment: That's precisely what I wanted when I said constructive, thanks very much Mamuka.